# Uso de la propiedad form de un botón con binding [] en Angular

Tags: angular, formularios, submit

Tengo el siguiente formulario:

**HTML**

```
<mat-card>
  <form novalidate id='myForm' (ngSubmit)="executeForm()" [formGroup]="formPrueba">
    <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput type="text" placeholder="Texto 1" formControlName='text1' autocomplete="off">
        <mat-error>El texto 1 es obligatorio</mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput type="text" placeholder="Texto 2" formControlName='text1' autocomplete="off">
        <mat-error>El texto 2 es obligatorio</mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
  </form>
</mat-card>

<button mat-stroked-button [form]='idForm'>Aceptar</button>
```

**TypeScript**

```
  public idForm = 'myForm';
  public formPrueba: FormGroup;
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.formPrueba = this.fb.group({
      text1: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
      text2: new FormControl(null, Validators.required)
    });
  }

  executeForm() {
    console.log('funciona');
  }
```

Necesito que el *submit* se encuentre afuera del formulario pero éste funcione con un binding de entrada `[form]="idForm"`, pero cuando realizo esta acción me muestra el error:

> Can't bind to 'form' since it isn't a known property of 'button'.

¿Existe otra forma de realizar esta acción?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para agregar atributos o propiedades al formulario como no reconoce como propiedades de ese elemento, las tienes que agregar de la siguiente forma. `[attr.propiedad]="valor"`

```
<button mat-stroked-button [attr.form]='idForm'>Aceptar</button>
```

Comment: Ohh ya veo, se me fue usar `attr` XD, gracias.